# How to customize sorting based on Column in SSRS reporting

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2017

I have created report by adding parent group on column with data as "ALL","Non-GD","GD",MileStone",Total" and report is rendered as expected.

But one issue I am facing is with sorting,by default grouping is happening in Alphabetical order.How can I override the default and provide an expression in such a way the rows should be ordered
"ALL","Non-GD","GD","Total","MileStone".

[image]

Please let me know how can we create an expression on RecordType column with the order of rows shown above.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with Group Sorting with below query and it worked.[image]